# react native app crash only in production(when test on phone)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I build react native v0.49 app and when i test it with emulator on phone on android and ios it works fine but when I build it using buddy build I see the first screen then i try to navigate to other page it navigate and then it crashes(exit from the app) without any error.
I tried to navigate to other component but same issue.
how can i get any idea why it's happening?
in emulator any navigation between components works without any issue.
but there is any way I can see log or something to know why it's happening?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues like this in React-Native before where the app would crash without giving me any error messages. If you have certain processes that are triggered when you navigate to another page, I would try commenting them out and then rebuilding to the the device to try to narrow down where the issue might lie. Basically, comment out chunks of functionality of your app to single out the problem.

My hunch is that too many events are beings triggered when you navigate to a new page.

Comment: umm actually, I don't have any processes that are triggered. just navigate between components. the project have many components and screens but I still didn't really use it into these screens where I navigate to... any way i can check it and get log?

Comment: you can debug your app on the device remotely in chrome. Throw in a bunch of debuggers and step through your app to see where it crashes. Not sure how to access logs of some sort.